# How to automatically cleanup a build agent working folder after a specific timespan

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I'd like to automatically cleanup working folder from our build agents if the workspace latest access date is older than one week (f.i.).

I have try the tfs sidekicks (for test this manually) and the tf commandline but I only delete the working folder info from the tfs database and never the physical folder from the assigned build agent folder.

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 0):

We use a custom powershell command for something similar, removing all exe and map files from previous builds.

The command is scheduled on our buildagent to run daily.

```
get-childitem e:\ -recurse -include *.exe,*.map | where-object {$_.directory -match "e:\\Build\\[0-9]" } | where-object {$_.lastwritetime -le (get-date).addDays(-7)} | del
```

**Breakdown**

Get all exe and map files from the e: drive

```
get-childitem e:\ -recurse -include *.exe,*.map
```

Where the folder structure matches our build folder

```
where-object {$_.directory -match "e:\\Build\\[0-9]" }
```

With a last writetime of 7 days ago

```
where-object {$_.lastwritetime -le (get-date).addDays(-7)}
```

Delete the files

```
del
```

Comment: Your command works only with the file system? You does not use tfs commands and does not synchonize the referencing workspaces? Works it well - no problems?

Comment: None so far but we started using TFS just a few months ago. I initially thought that the builds retention policy would clean up our buildagents but somehow it doesn't seem to work that way *(my understanding of it is wrong or our implementation is wrong...)*. The script was created as a quick fix until we find the time to investigate this further.

Comment: Great script, however if like me, you are getting "Not enough permissions", make sure you run PowerShell "as administrator".  If you still have problems, add " -force" to the end of this script